# Jquery - detect play on Youtube's object tag

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I use `object` tag to embed a youtube video.

```
<object data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/QwievZ1Tx-8" width="100%" height="315"></object>
```

I would like to trigger an Ajax request (So the server can update the database's view count on the video) everytime the video play.

Anybody know how to do it ?,

**NOTE :** Let say the user click 'play' on the video, AJAX REQUEST CALLED. But when they pause and resume the video, AJAX REQUEST DID NOT CALLED.

Comment: You can use the way youtube tells you to do this. By using the [iframe api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player) and listen to `onStateChange`.

Comment: On state change were invoke even when user resume. I dont want it to invoke when resume.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in script:

```
$("object")[0].onplay = function () {
    //AJAX REQUEST CALLED
};
```

**OR:**

```
<object... onplay="myFunction()">
```

and in the script

```
myFunction(){
//AJAX REQUEST CALLED
}
```

It happend only when the video start to play...

Comment: I add alert('a') to myFunction() and its not alerting anything when i press play.

Answer (score 0):

You can use youtube iframe api and the callback [`onPlayerStateChange`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player) which calling with the `event` object which have the exact event type for it. Also, keep a flag if the video is already started and call the ajax only if it didn't.

Like this:

```js
var isStarted = false;
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == 1 && !isStarted) {
    // call ajax
    isStarted = true;
  }
}
```